# Running docker login through subprocess.Popen() returns but does not continue following lines of code. Using subprocess.run() works. Why?

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, python-3.7

When I run:

```
>>> subprocess.run('docker login  https://index.docker.io/v1/', shell=True)
Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in ~/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
0
>>> a = 1 + 2 # I can continue my program
```

However when I run:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen('docker login  https://index.docker.io/v1/', shell=True)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f951e144ad0>
>>> Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in ~/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded

# I cannot continue my program. Code does not continue
```

I notice the >>> returning for the Popen earlier due to it being a non blocking call. This means my program stalls and does not continue with running the code following it. I could not find an answer to why this happens. I wanted to reach out here.

Comment: So, what is hanging here? As you write, `subprocess.Popen(...)` returns early. It does not seem to be hanging or stalling?

Comment: Hi, when I run it in a program, you notice that the interpreter in the ```subprocess.Popen(...)``` call returns early but I cannot run any following commands after it. In the ```subprocess.run(...) || subprocess.call(...)```, you can see that I am allowed to type new commands. Hence the ```>>>```. I get that it is a blocking  statement and that's why. I just do not get why I cannot continue with the ```subprocess.Popen(...)``` So in my code, it stalls there. Seems like there is no ''callback" to alert the process to continue.

Comment: I believe you need to do `subprocess.Popen('docker login ...', shell=True).wait()`